# Android ndk different cflags

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, ndk-build

I have 3 projects in Android Studio: producer, consumer, and lib.

Lib is a shared JNI library in which I define a few functions to behave differently while others the same depending on how they're used. For example:

```
void function() {
#ifdef PRODUCER
  printf("I'm a producer!\n");
#endif // PRODUCER
#ifdef CONSUMER
  printf("I'm a consumer!\n");
#endif // CONSUMER
}
```

I'd like my gradle.build script for lib to basically have two potential flavors: producer & consumer then specify a dependency in the other projects like compile project(':lib:producer') or project(':lib:consumer'). These different targets would only vary in the following:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            cFlag "-DPRODUCER" // or -DCONSUMER
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the best thing to do here was upgrade to Android Studio 2.2+ then use the externalNativeBuild's CMake to generate multiple libraries.